# I did not Import the Recycler View AndroidX Library, yet, I am using it. Why and How is it working?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, androidx

```
build.gradle(app)

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.todolistapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    // Room
    def room_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    // For Floating Action Button
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

as you can see from my dependencies, I did not import the recycled view Androidx library.

> androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0

but as shown below, I can comfortably use it in my layout (activity_main.xml) and MainActivity code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewTasks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), TaskAdapter.TaskViewCliskListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerViewTasks.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
}
```

What is responsible for this behavior?

Comment: Undr this dependencies com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0  ,It occurs.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As per the [dependencies of the `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.material/material/1.0.0):

> androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0

This means that the Material library takes a transitive dependency on RecyclerView already and you don't need to manually include it yourself.

Comment: Not unless some newer version of RecyclerView and you want to manually include that newer version. That's not the case right now though, so there's no need to explicitly add it right now.

Answer (score 9):

> I did not Import the Recycler View AndroidX Library, yet i am using. Why and How is it working?

Because you have added the dependencies of `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

No need to add `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0` if youhave already added `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`

Comment: This was very helpful since I didn't find reference for that in official Docs :/

Comment: @AliEzzatOdeh happy to hear that buddy

Comment: Can't accept it because I am not the one who asked the question in the first place, all what I can do for you is to vote up and it is already done from the last time ;)

Comment: @AliEzzatOdeh sorry by mistake I have tagged u in comment

Answer (score 5):

`com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` Includes The **`RecyclerView`** Component So you dont need to add it externally.

if you added `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0`to your app dependencies you don't need to add `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0` to your dependencies because it already included in **material library**.

For Additional Information https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

Answer (score 4):

In case your question is about using a different version than the one in the `material` dependencies.

I was trying to use alpha version of `recyclerview` every time I add the `androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview` dependency manually the code works fine on build time.
But the App keeps crashing because it can't find the new classes I use from the alpha version of the `recyclerview` on runtime.

I tried to use the latest alpha version of `material` dependency but it also depends on the latest stable version on `recyclerview` .. so it didn't help.

To solve it I excluded the `recyclerview` decency from `material` and added the `recyclerview` decency myself like this.

```
implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0") {
    exclude(group = "androidx.recyclerview", module = "recyclerview")
}
implementation("androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04")
```

Comment: [An updated version](https://gist.github.com/lmj0011/229959d56c99efb067f494e78358228a) of this answer since the queue is full.

Comment: Didn't know this was possible. Thanks for sharing that! I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and tested.The `com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0` includes `RecyclerView` too. Might be it is here to give material design look n feel same like as `MaterialButton`

Answer (score 1):

```
dependencies{

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
```

or

dependencies{

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:your version'

}
```

if you already added

com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0
or
com.android.support:design:version

in the previous version of android recyclerview into design library but in the version of Androidx its on material library.

in your dependencies then recyclerview dependencies is not needed. its already added in material/design library

[Check Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings)

for Details Android Library

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: why this doesn't the answer . i provide the answer how work androidx Recyclerview dependencies. what the wrong i do here? What you want to know actually? you can ask me. i can help you.

Comment: Try and read. The question is `I did not Import the Recycler View AndroidX Library, yet, i am using it. Why and How is it working?`. So you tell me, are you answering the question? Also, yes I can see that you edited the answer https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56700924/3